# Will bobcats climb cacti when not in fear of their lives?

Tags: animal-behaviour, bobcats

There are pictures of bobcats [climbing on top of really tall cacti](http://om/search?as_st=y&tbm=isch&as_q=bobcats%20on%20cactus&as_epq=&as_oq=&as_eq=&imgsz=&imgar=&imgc=&imgcolor=&imgtype=&cr=&as_sitesearch=&safe=images&as_filetype=&as_rights=), [the one story](https://bigcatrescue.org/bobcat-on-cactus/) I read says that the reason the bobcat climbed the tree was to get away from a mountian lion who was trying <s>give it a hug</s> eat it.

Would a **bobcat climb a cactus if it wasn't being chased by a predator?**